# impossible to retrieve the image width if the css attribute is not set

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, browser

On all browsers but firefox , It seems impossible to retrieve the image width if the css attribute is not set, I tried all the codes that I found but cannot solve this Issue, Here is the Html code

```
<div class="slide"><img src="../images/image1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="../images/image2.jpg"/></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="../images/image3.jpg"/></div>
```

and  Javascript

```
    var slideWidth = parseInt($('.slide').find('img:first').css('width'));
    alert(slideWidth);      //Works on FF but not Other browsers 
    var slideWidth = $('.slide').children('div > img:first').width();
    alert(slideWidth);        //Works on FF but not Other browsers
```

the alert will show you the right width on FF but will show 0 on others
Is there any way to solve this problem , Thank you..

Here an Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/j82s6/

Comment: Your code works fine if you select onLoad option in jsfiddle. (I'm using Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/j82s6/4/

Comment: search this site...many many posts on how to handle individual image load event

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wait for the image to load first - other browsers are retrieving the width before the image loaded. Use the `.load()` event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M6TxJ/  
JS:

```
$('.slide img:first').load(function(){
    var slideWidth = parseInt($('.slide').find('img:first').css('width'));
    alert(slideWidth);      //Works on FF but not Other browsers 
    var slideWidth = $('.slide').children('div > img:first').width();
    alert(slideWidth);

});
```

Comment: That will work fine even with `.ready()` function. Even OP's code works if we select onLoad option in jsfiddle. (I'm using Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/j82s6/4/

Comment: Ah ah , Thank you  .. @ Milijan  : Iam using this code inside a jQuery plugin

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I'm assuming this would be used outside of JSFiddle, and in that condition you cannot set onLoad jQuery without some extra scripts, which I doubt JohnTaa is using.

Comment: not a reliable method... read disclaimer regarding images in jQuery docs. If image is cached in some browsers `load` doesn't fire. Many many posts on this site for `jquery image preload`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you select `onLoad` option in jsfiddle (I'm using Chrome).

http://jsfiddle.net/j82s6/4/

Make sure that you put your code inside this

```
$(document).ready(function{
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Just saying, the ready function does not work if you have a really large image to load (demonstrated in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcXDy/1))

Comment: In Domready function this will not work if we attached the selector to a jquery plugin but with kpsuperplane  load function it works , anyway thank you all

Comment: That is true, I didn't know that :) I've just tried to avoid `.load()` (maybe OP will try to load some page via .load(), some js code will not work, etc... you know what I mean) :)